# Unknown icon on Windows 11 thumbnails

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, icons, thumbnails

I don't know how it happened, but now on my Windows 11, I see strange thumbnail icons on files in my C:\Users folder and all subfolders inside. I don't see that on other partitions/drives or locations.

I've been trying to set everything off in Explorer properties, but it's still there. It's possible I added it with some program, but I don't know which and how to get rid of it.

I thought it may be something with sharing settings or [Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html), that I've installed recently, but I'm not sure.

Do you have any idea how to check where it came from or how to remove it?

[image: example of file]

Comment: Can you try checking with [ShExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)? Configure it to hide all MS extensions first, and maybe sort by type, then look for anything that reminds you of a recently installed or possibly relevant program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known "feature", as stated on the [MS support site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-removeresize-double-arrow-blue-box-overlay/f30933c7-6151-4d1e-9a4a-4b1eed2c85c2):

> These icon overlays occur when you have a third party antivirus
> installed which created a backup, thus showing a checkmark or double
> arrow (blue box) overlay along with the icon. The icon displayed in
> the screenshot indicates that the file has been changed by its last
> back.
>
> Therefore, If you do not wish to see these overlays I would suggest
> you to go to the third party antivirus settings and remove/uncheck
> Backup status indicators.

In case of Norton Antivirus you need to:

> It was Norton Security Backup that gave this annoying symbol. By turn it of in Norton Security Preferences  and icons for security back up it was gone.

There is an explanation on the [Norton forum](https://community.norton.com/en/forums/disable-backup-status-indicators-windows-explorer) as well:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the tip with [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html), it solved my problem. I was able to identify it quickly:

[image]

It was norton antivirus in my case. Please remember to click Options and Restart Explorer after you disable something.